# robot framework REST interface

Tags: robotframework

Does robot framework have any capability to expose a REST interface to run/stop tests and provide status?  I need some sort of stateless capability to manage tests and so on.  Is there a way to limit how many tests that can run in parallel, so that a executed test either gets queued or runs in parallel?

I went through 'remote server' documentation at https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer but didn't think this did what I wanted it to do.

Can someone provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not provide any sort of server that can be used to control tests via a REST interface. Robot also has no support for running tests in parallel. There is a separate tool that can be used to run robot tests in parallel: [pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot)

If you need a restful interface, you might want to look at a ci server such as [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).

Comment: For capacity management using Jenkins is one approach to ensure your nodes are not overutilised. If your tests are browser based using one of the selenium libraries, then using pabot in combination with Selenium Grid allows you to do something similar.